# Swagger API documentation

Tags: python, django

I saw swagger documentation of [Flask](https://github.com/rantav/flask-restful-swagger) and [Django](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger). In Flask I can design and document my API hand-written.(Include which fields are required, optional etc. under parameters sections).

**Here's how we do in Flask**

```
class Todo(Resource):
    "Describing elephants"
    @swagger.operation(
        notes='some really good notes',
        responseClass=ModelClass.__name__,
        nickname='upload',
        parameters=[
            {
              "name": "body",
              "description": "blueprint object that needs to be added. YAML.",
              "required": True,
              "allowMultiple": False,
              "dataType": ModelClass2.__name__,
              "paramType": "body"
            }
          ],
        responseMessages=[
            {
              "code": 201,
              "message": "Created. The URL of the created blueprint should be in the Location header"
            },
            {
              "code": 405,
              "message": "Invalid input"
            }
          ]
        )
```

I can chose which parameters to include, and which not. **But how do I implement the same in Django?** [Django-Swagger Document](https://github.com/marcgibbons/django-rest-swagger) in 
not good at all. My main issue is how do I write my raw-json in Django.

In Django it automates it which does not allows me to customize my json. **How do I implement the same kind of thing on Django?**

Here is **models.py** file

```
class Controller(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key = True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 255, unique = True)
    ip = models.CharField(max_length = 255, unique = True)
    installation_id = models.ForeignKey('Installation')
```

**serializers.py**

```
class ActionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Controller
        fields = ('installation',)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns
from modules.actions import views as views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'(?P<installation>[0-9]+)', views.ApiActions.as_view()),
)
```

**views.py**

```
class ApiActions(APIView):

    """
    Returns controllers List
    """

    model = Controller
    serializer_class = ActionSerializer 

    def get(self, request, installation,format=None):

        controllers = Controller.objects.get(installation_id = installation)
        serializer = ActionSerializer(controllers)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

My questions are

**1)** If I need to add a field say `xyz`, which is not in my models how do I add it?

**2)** Quiet similar to **1st**, If i need to add a field which accepts values b/w 3 provided values,ie a dropdown. how do I add it?

**3)** How I add an optional field? (since in case of `PUT` request, I might only update 1 field and rest leave it blank, which means `optional`  field).

**4)** Also how do I add a field that accepts the json string, as [this](http://sort.t.greyorangerobotics.com/api/docs/#!/trigger/triggerNotification_post_0) api does?

Thanks

I can do all of these things in Flask by hardcoding my api. But in Django, it automates from my models, which does not(as I believe) gives me the access to customize my api. In Flask, I just need to write my API with hands and then integrate with the Swagger. **Does this same thing exist in Django?**

Like I just need to add  the following **json** in my Flask code and it will answer all my questions.

```
# Swagger json:
    "models": {
        "TodoItemWithArgs": {
            "description": "A description...",
            "id": "TodoItem",
            "properties": {
                "arg1": { # I can add any number of arguments I want as per my requirements.
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "arg2": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "arg3": {
                    "default": "123",
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "arg1",
                "arg2" # arg3 is not mentioned and hence 'opional'
            ]
        },
```

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34591291/show-maximum-minimum-and-default-in-swagger-for-django-rest-framework/37922613#37922613) answer can be useful for you

Comment: Are you using Django REST Framework? If so, did you check out [their docs for adding swagger](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/documenting-your-api/)?

Answer (score 0):

Would this work:

```
class TriggerView(APIView):
    """
    This text is the description for this API
        mykey -- My Key parameter
    """

    authentication_classes = (BasicAuthentication,)
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        print request.DATA
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_202_ACCEPTED)
```

the POST request:

```
Authorization:Basic YWRtaW46cGFzcw==
Content-Type:application/json

{"mykey": "myvalue"}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying. How will I go for `put` request? What I currently do is include selected fields in the `Serializer` class like `class ActionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
 class Meta:
  model = Controller
  fields = ('installation_id','ip','xyz','abc')` and this way all the fields are listed, but none is **optional**, every field is **required**. **1)** How I add the optional field? **2)** Also how I add a field that accepts the `json` string.? **3)** How do I add a field which accepts values b/w 3 provided values,ie a dropdown.? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @python-coder Please put all the details in you question, model definition, serializer, view, urls..

Comment: Please see my edited question. I've added my models, serializers,urls and views.